# get and set property value of one user control from another inside the later usercontrol method

Tags: c#, web-user-controls

I have two usercontrol U1 and U2. Now in U1 i have one override method(`void Commit()`) and one public string property(`NewCompanyID`). From U2 i have to call U1 `commit()` method and inside the commit method i have to set the `NewCompanyID` public property.

Code are as follows :

**U2 code**

```
 //some code 
obj.Commit();
CompanyId = obj.NewCompanyID;
```

**U1 Code**

```
    public string NewCompanyID
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(ViewState["NewCompanyId"])))
                return string.Empty;
            return Convert.ToString(ViewState["NewComapnyId"]);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["NewCompanyId"] = value;
        }
    }
```

---

```
public override void Commit()

{

    // Some code

    NewCompanyID = results.Entity.Id.ToString();
 }
```

In Output `NewCompanyID` is returning blank.

Comment: Is it possible that `results.Entity.Id` is blank?

Comment: `NewComapnyId` is misspelled in your property's `return`. Is that just a typo here, or is that actually in your code?

Comment: No results.Entity.Id is returning value.

Comment: Thanks Manny.It is misspelled but even after that i am not getting NewCompanyId value. Is it possible to get ViewState value of one control from another?

Comment: I have got the solution. I was not passing the reference to that usercontrol. Ur answer showed me the way to get the solution. Thanks Manny